# How to check packages required by Django project?

Tags: python, django, pip, package

I inherited old Django project and now I have to expand it.
Unfortunately there was no virtualenv for this project and in system there is installed a lot of junk form several other python applications.

Is there a way to check what packages are precisely  required by my project except by removing packages one by one?

Comment: Look at `INSTALLED_APPS` and grep for import statements?

Comment: You have to check each one ..!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at py2depgraph (from http://www.tarind.com/depgraph.html).  It uses the Python `modulefinder` module, and will probably require some tweaks to do be most helpful, but the code is pretty short and easy to read.